# Change TextView Color Depending On Text

Tags: java, android, textview, ondraw

Using onDraw, I want to make a custom text view that changes color depending on its text value. For example, if the text value is "hello" I want it to be red and if it says "bye" I want it to be green. Any helps greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it in a more creative way using onDraw.

```
public class MagnitudeTextView extends TextView {

public MagnitudeTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MagnitudeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MagnitudeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.TextView#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();

    int px = width / 2;
    int py = height / 2;

    Paint Red = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Red.setColor(Color.RED);

    Paint White = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    White.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    Paint Yellow = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Yellow.setARGB(210, 105, 30, 0);

    Paint Blue = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    float textWidth = Red.measureText(String.valueOf(getText()));

    String g = String.valueOf(getText());
    if (g.startsWith("3") || g.startsWith("4")) {
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(getText()), px - textWidth / 2, py,
                White);
    }

    if (g.startsWith("6") || g.startsWith("5") || g.startsWith("7")
            || g.startsWith("8")) {
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(getText()), px - textWidth / 2, py,
                Yellow);
    }

    if (g.startsWith("9") || g.startsWith("10")) {
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(getText()), px - textWidth / 2, py,
                Red);
    }
    // super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I'm not necessarily sure why you want to do this in `onDraw()`. Unless you have a really good reason to set up a custom `TextView`/`EditText`, that's not necessary.

**To simplify your situation**, you can implement a `TextWatcher` to do this, and in `onTextChanged()`, you can set the color by comparing the string values using `.equals()`.

Here is an example of your theoretical situation:

```
final EditText yourEditText = /* findViewById maybe? */;
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))
            yourEditText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
            yourEditText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else // if it says neither "hello" nor "bye"
            yourEditText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Nothing needs to happen here
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Nothing needs to happen here
    }
});
```

**If you feel its necessary to maintain this in `onDraw()`**, simply extract the code from `onTextChanged()` and change `yourEditText` to `this`, or place it in the constructor instead:

```
public class YourTextView extends TextView { // Or extends EditText, doesn't matter
    public YourTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public YourTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public YourTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            // Copy the TextWatcher code from the example above, replacing "yourEditText" with "YourTextView.this"
        });
    }

    // ... Rest of your class
}
```

Comment: I need to do this in onDraw as I clearly expressed in my question because I need this textview to be a custom listview row item.

Comment: Well, you don't need a custom `TextView` for that, but you can use exactly the same code and just attach this `TextWatcher` to the `TextView` in its constructor.

Comment: @DroidDevAge13 I've edited my post to try to explain what I was getting at above. Hopefully it's clear enough.. ;)

Comment: what is 'yourEditText' at the beginning of line 10. I'm also getting this error 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher) from the type TextView'

Comment: Something you're doing is not akin to what I've written. You should be using the code from the second half, then following the comments within it. Your final code should have no `static` references, and should not have any references to `yourEditText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite setText() and set the color using setTextColor().

You can do it inside onDraw as well, but it's not worth the weigth, as it may pass many times inside onDraw.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the text:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textid);
String value = text.getText().toString();
```

Then check what the text is and change the color :

```
if (value.equals("hello")) {

    text.setBackgroundColor(yourcolor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement TextWatcher and use `onTextChanged()`

More about it here in the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)